# String to Date, not accordance

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class formatTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String str  = "2017-08-07 6:6:6";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(str);
            Date date = sdf.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the expected outcome of your code? And what result do you in fact get instead? When asking about why your code doesn’t work as expected, always be clear about expected result and how observed result differs, please. So that we may help you.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome (yours is just one example out of very , very many). Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("2017-08-07 6:6:6", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd H:m:s"))`. This produces a date and time of `2017-08-07T06:06:06`.

Answer (score 1):

Change YYYY to yyyy

```
    String str = "2017-08-07 06:06:06";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.